# Android cannot open drawer inside onReceivedError

Tags: android

I have this code within `onCreate`:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    .
    .
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/error.html");
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        progress.dismiss();
        // onBackPressed(); // this doesn't open the drawer either
    }

});
```

When there is no internet connection it successfully detects the error and loads `error.html`. However, it refuses to open the drawer. Also, it closes the progress dialog whether I comment out that line or not. And, when I try calling `onBackPressed()`, it also fails to open the drawer.

The drawer opens and closes fine when the back button is pressed:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
}
```

Why will the drawer not open inside onReceivedError?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the drawer layout reference (drawer) inside onReceivedError, try by declaring the drawer as instance variable and get the reference at onCreate itself.

I tried and able to open & close the drawer, below is the sample.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) 
                               findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, 
                                       fragment).commit();
    }

    public  class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
    private WebView webView;


    public PlanetFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
        this.webView = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);



        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/error.html");
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        return rootView;
    }
}
 }
```